# How to delete all phone numbers with Twilio Java SDK?

Tags: java, twilio

I am using Twilio JAVA SDK. I don't have the sid of a phone number. How do I delete all numbers?
My account have 820 phone numbers.

I find this api to get all phone numbers sid but it doesn't work.

curl -G https://preview.twilio.com/Numbers/ActiveNumbers 
-u '<ACCOUNT_SID:AUTH_TOKEN>'

Answer (score 0):

Try using the example below.

[List all IncomingPhoneNumber resources for your account](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource)

Comment: Thanks, this way I can get phone number SID by phone number, but I don't have phone numbers array. How can I get my account phone numbers?